# Mobile games demographic data

Tags: data-request, usa, demographics, games

I'm looking for demographic data for mobile games.

I've looked at [App Annie](https://www.appannie.com/), [SensorTower](https://sensortower.com/), and [Apptrace](http://www.apptrace.com/). These three sources give estimates on the app store ratings, number of downloads, and rankings in each country -- but their free versions provide no information as to WHO is using these apps/games. I want to get a better idea of WHO the users are.

**Data** - I'm looking for information regarding players' age, sex, ethnicity, income, race, and basically anything that could assist in targeting mobile users in a more precise manner. Monetization is key. My clients, of course, are interested in targeting users who are spending money.

**Region** - English speaking markets (primarily North America and Western Europe)

Any format or source is acceptable. I'm looking for any kind of data regarding mobile gaming in English markets -- and I will, of course, try to assess the credibility on my own. Essentially, I'm looking for free and open estimates/analytics -- as signing up for a subscription based service is pricy for a small business.

Comment: aware of a large dataset but its from china...

Comment: I don't mind. I can speak and read Chinese -- so that shouldn't be a problem. :-)

Comment: ok. well another possible problem, this data isn't entirely for games, just apps....but if you find it useful, i'll repost this as an answer https://www.kaggle.com/c/talkingdata-mobile-user-demographics/data

Comment: I followed the link and apparently that data isn't free (or open). Thanks for the help, though!

Comment: i just accessed and downloaded it. its free. open is debatable, but all you have to do is have an account.

Comment: Oh! I figured I had to have a paid account! I'll revisit the website and see if I can register and get the download! Thanks!